# Sails v1.0: error while using custom primary key with mongo

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm giving a try to the beta version of SailsJS (v1.0.0-32) and I'm having some issues while configuring a custom id. Bellow you'll find my current configuration:

The `modelExample.js`

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    id:{
      type: 'string',
      columnName: '_id'
    },
    attr: {
      type: 'number'
    }
  }
}
```

The model config `config/models.js`

```
attributes: {
    createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true, },
    updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true, },
    id: { type: 'string', columnName: '_id' },
}
```

The element trying to be inserted:

`{id:"600000", attr:40}`

The `error` I get when trying to create a record with an attribute "id" included in the element trying to be created:

```
AdapterError: Unexpected error from database adapter: Invalid primary key value provided for `id`.  Cannot interpret `600000` as a Mongo id.
(Usually, this is the result of a bug in application logic.)
```

Seems that mongo does not like the string `600000` as an `id`, but I'm not sure if maybe I'm misunderstanding something related to ids in mongo. In the old version of sails, I never had this issue since the id override was straightforward.

For more information, the sails-mongo adapter version is: `"sails-mongo": "^1.0.0-5"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use non-ObjectID primary keys with `sails-mongo` in Sails 1.0, you have to set `dontUseObjectIds: true` in your model, for example:

```
// api/models/User.js
module.exports = {
  dontUseObjectIds: true,
  attributes: {
    id: { type: 'number', columnName: '_id' }, // <-- still need to set `columnName`!
    name: { type: 'string' },
    ...etc...
  }
}
```

This is implemented as of `sails-mongo` v1.0.0-7.